# Attempting to move a character in an array list using Junit

Tags: java, arraylist, junit

I am trying to move the character P up, down, left, and right depending on the number given to the move method, unfortunately the Junit tester is failing giving me this: org.junit.ComparisonFailure: failed test expected:<*******
[ P]   *
*     *
***** *> but was:<***
[P  ]   *
*     *
***** *>

The print should look like this :

---

P    *
 *     *

---

Game Class:

```
public class Game {

    public static final int UP = 1;
    public static final int DOWN = 2;
    public static final int LEFT = 3;
    public static final int RIGHT = 4;

    String[][] board; //Creates a matrix a rows and j columns
    int playerRow, playerCol;

    public Game(int a, int j) {

        board = new String[a][j]; //Creates a matrix a rows and j columns
        playerCol = 0;
        playerRow = 1;

        for(int row =0; row < a; row++){
            for(int col = 0; col < j; col++){
                board [row] [col] =" ";
            }
        }

        //Fills the first row with *s
        for (int i=0; i < j ; i++){
            board [0][i] ="*";
        }



        //Place *s across the bottom row
        for (int i=1; i<j; i++){
            board [a-1][i] = "*";
        }

        //Place *s down the right side
        for (int i=0; i < a ; i++){
            board [i][0] ="*";
            board [i][j-1] ="*";
        }

        //Place the player on the first column of the second row
                board [1] [0] = "P";

        board [a-1][j-2] =" ";

    }

    public String toString(){
        String output = "";
        for(int row =0; row < board.length; row++){
            for(int col = 0; col < board[0].length; col++){
                output += board[row][col];
            }
            output += "\n";
        }
        output = (String) output.subSequence(0, output.length()-1);
        return output;
    }

    public void move(int a){
        if(a == Game.UP){

            playerRow -= 1;
        }

        if(a == Game.DOWN){
            playerRow += 1;
        }

        if(a == Game.LEFT){
            playerCol -= 1;
        }

        if(a == Game.RIGHT){
            playerCol += 1;
        }
    }

}
```

Game Tester:

```
import static org.junit.Assert.*;

import org.junit.Test;


public class GameTester {

    @Test
    public void test() {
        Game g = new Game(3,4);
        String result = g.toString();
        String shouldBe="****\nP  *\n** *";
        //****
        //P  *
        //** *
        assertEquals("failed test", shouldBe, result);
        Game g2 = new Game(4,7);
        result = g2.toString();
        shouldBe="*******\nP     *\n*     *\n***** *";
        //*******
        //P     *
        //*     *
        //***** *
        assertEquals("failed test", shouldBe, result);
        g2.move(Game.RIGHT);
        shouldBe ="*******\n P   *\n*     *\n***** *";
        //*******
        // P    *
        //*     *
        //***** *
        assertEquals("failed test", shouldBe, result);



        //Make a 2D Matrix to hold all the positions and make it move
    }

}
```

Comment: //*******
// P    *
//*     *
//***** *

Answer (score 0):

I believe you have a couple problems in the code:

```
- as part of the move to the right code, you correctly set the playerCol value up by 1 but board is not updated to move the 'P' to the next column.
- as a result of the above code, the toString() still shows the player in col 0
- you don't call result = g2.toString(); after moving to the right, so the result is still left over from the previous move
- the assert is using the stale version of result
- I believe no matter how you move, the player will always be shown in the same position, as a result of the 1st item.
- the shouldBe value for the row with the player only has 6 slots, whereas the board has 7 columns - so that expected result needs to be udpated.
```

Hope this helps!